# Magento - How can I pass UserId instead of OrderId to ADYEN SKIN

Tags: magento, payment

I'm using adyen to pay by credit cards and I notice that when the user pays, the module on Magento passes the order id as MerchantReference to Adyen. 
In order to activate the "remember my data" during the payment using adyen SKIN, I need to pass the UserId and not the orderId.

Any suggestion how to solve it?

--- More info ---

This is the specific module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/adyen-payment.html

And, this is the form example that we generate for the payments on Adyen, in another environment. As you can see, the merchantReference is an unique value, which identify the first user payment. This values is calculated using UserId, so we could identify the user for his next payments.

I should need to know where the plugin Adyen (for Magento) generate this form, so I could change the merchantReference parameter using UserId and not OrderId

```
<form action="https://test.adyen.com/hpp/pay.shtml" 
      method="post" id="gatewayPaymentForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="merchantReference" value="Ajx">
      <input type="hidden" name="paymentAmount" value="2900">
      <input type="hidden" name="currencyCode"  value="EUR">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipBeforeDate" value="2013-02-03">
      <input type="hidden" name="skinCode" value="XDFGG">
      <input type="hidden" name="merchantAccount" value="NameAccount">
      <input type="hidden" name="shopperLocale" value="es">
      <input type="hidden" name="sessionValidity" value="2013-01-31T16:35:31+01:00">
      <input type="hidden" name="merchantSig" value="bcbXNhsd">
      <input type="hidden" name="shopperEmail" value="asd@gmail.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="shopperReference" value="5">
      <input type="hidden" name="recurringContract" value="ONECLICK">
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: It would help to share some more infos on that specific module, because almost no one will know it. You should thus include at least the necessary code or at the very very least a link to the module.

Comment: I just updated the information requested by @mpaepper

Comment: Just keep in mind that a userid can have many orders, so if you change MerchantReference to userid then it will be difficult to to reference a particular order

Comment: Thanks for your comment @R.S, all we need is to have a unique ID, but we don't know how to modify the form to display a hidden field with that UserID neither how obtain this information.

Comment: Could you post the source code that generate the above code

Comment: Already solved. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved, we modified the file: /Madia/Adyen/Model/Adyen/Hpp.php

```
//To identify and remind user data with mail.
$adyFields['shopperReference'] = $customerEmail;
```

It works for us.